# Taking Photo from Android Camera to Change 2 ImageViews

Tags: android, button, camera, imageview

Below is some code which is working somewhat…I currently have 2 ImageViews on my Screen and below each is a button. When the button is clicked the camera function opens. My aim is that the button below one imageviews changes just that image view, leaving me able to then click the other button to change the other. However at the moment when I change one, they both change to the same photo. I had previous tried a few ‘if’ statements by initialising each to a variable called “currentImage” but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

```
public class NowThen extends Activity {

Bitmap photo;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.nowthen);
}

public void nowPhoto (View view){
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);   
}

public void thenPhoto (View view){
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);   
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (data != null) {

        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView nowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nowImage);
        ImageView thenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thenImage);

        nowImage.setImageBitmap(photo); 
        thenImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

        Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
    }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your thenPhoto code to this:

```
public void thenPhoto (View view){
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);   
}
```

And change your onActivityResult to this :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (data != null) {

        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView nowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nowImage);

        nowImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

        Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
    }
 } else if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (data != null) {

        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView thenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thenImage);

        thenImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

        Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
    }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct except that you are starting the intent with same requestCode 0. Due to this the same block is called in your onActivityResult() block.

```
startActivityForResult(intent,0);//for first button
startActivityForResult(intent,1);//for second button
```

Now check your requestCode in your onAcitivityResult() code in a if or switch statement.